# Node.js: event emitters not firing properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter, minimatch

I created a project that recursively looks for valid media file types from an array of directories. The issue is that two of my event emitters are working correctly and two are not. I've read the docs, watched some videos, and searched this site looking for answers. I think there is something fundamental that I'm missing or not understanding that is getting in the way.

I have a file called directoryWatch.js with the following code.

```
let util = require('util');
let EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
let recursive = require('recursive-readdir');
let mm = require("minimatch");
let local = require('../_localData/environmentConfig');

let validMediaFiles = function(dirs){
    let self = this;
    self.emit('start',`${local.dirScanStart}`);
    dirs.forEach(function(dirName){
        recursive(dirName, function (err, files) {
            if(err){
                self.emit('error',`${local.dirScanError} ${dirName}`);
            } else{
                self.emit('success',`${local.dirScanSuccess} ${dirName}`,
                    mm.match(files, local.validFileExtensions, 
                   {matchBase: true, nocase: true, nonull: true}));
            }
        });
    });
    self.emit('end',`${local.errScanMsg}`);
};

util.inherits(validMediaFiles, EventEmitter);

module.exports = validMediaFiles;
```

I have 4 events I want to emit.

1. The start step of looking at the directories.
2. The errors from trying to find a directory.
3. The success from reading a directory.
4. The end step of looking at the directories.

My main.js file that I'm executing looks like this.

```
let local = require('./_localData/environmentConfig');
let dirWatch = require('./fileIO/directoryWatch');

let results = new dirWatch(local.directories);

results.on('start',function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});

results.on('error',function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});

results.on('success',function(msg,files){
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(files);
});

results.on('end',function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
```

The output in Powershell looks like this

```
PS G:\Javascrpt Projects\Node\Misc\Test2>
PS G:\Javascrpt Projects\Node\Misc\Test2> node main.js
Error scanning directory: ssdfdsfasf
Getting media from: G:\Javascrpt Projects\Node\Misc\Test2\TestFiles\music
Getting media from: G:\Javascrpt Projects\Node\Misc\Test2\TestFiles\music2
{....big list of file names goes here...}
```

The issue is that my "start" event and "end" event are getting ignored, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: (Totally unrelated, but why interpolate a single string? E.g., `${local.errScanMsg}` is already just a string, right?

Comment: The example was heavily cut back from the original code. It does a lot more than I'm showing.